# Is there any way to get Cupid's Arrows, other than grinding?

Tags: pangenesis

### Is there any way to get cupid's arrow, other than grinding?

The game I'm talking about is called Pangenesis.

https://pangenesisgame.com/

https://www.reddit.com/r/pangenesis

Info:

There's an item in Pangenesis called 'Cupids Arrow', which, when shot at any creature, (possibly including oneself, not sure) a half egg will be dropped. Combine any two half eggs to combine the species of each half egg into one full egg – two identical half eggs will make no changes.

The only way I've ever found Cupid's Arrows is by grinding – killing the Peeks and Arachnids in the Labyrinth, under the Town.

The question:

Is there any easier way to obtain Cupid's Arrows? Grinding is too tedious, and I would like to breed creatures easily. I've checked the shop of the Local, but he/she only sells Arrows, Bombs and Pickaxes...

Any help appreciated,

wolfboyft

Comment: I understand that this game is extremely... not well known, so... it is unlikely that there will be an answer any time soon, if ever. But! This question will surely grow the game in popularity!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can craft them by combining 4 red pomesors with an arrow. You can find quite a bit extra information about the game in [this forum thread](http://forums.somethingawful.com/showthread.php?threadid=3677674&userid=0&perpage=40&pagenumber=1).

Comment: Wiki seemed empty. Glad to know there's more to discover!

Comment: Actually, that is one of the few things you can find on the wiki.

Comment: D'oh! My bad...